# 3D rotation on 3 axis; Java

Tags: java, math, 3d, rotation, lwjgl

I'm working on a 3d game engine (LWJGL3) and I'm really stuck on rotation object around parent.

Here is some outline:

1. Each `GameObject` can have other `GameObject` as child.
2. Each `GameObject` has a `Transform` class:

```java
public Vector3f translation;
public Quaternion rotation;
public Vector3f scale;

public Transform() {
    this.translation = new Vector3f(0.0f);
    this.rotation = new Quaternion();
    this.scale = new Vector3f(1.0f);
}
```

The `Quaternion` class extends the `Quaternionf` from **JOML lib** with some extra methods, but you can consider it as a pure JOML class. When I add a `GameObject` to another, it updates its *local transforms* so it inherits parents translation, rotation and scale:

```
public void updateToParent(GameObject parent) {
    this.translation.add(parent.getWorldTransform().translation);
    rotateAroundParent(parent.getWorldTransform());
    this.scale.mul(parent.getWorldTransform().scale);
}

private void rotateAroundParent(Transform transform) {
    this.translation.sub(transform.translation);
    this.translation.rotateZ(-transform.rotation.z);
    this.translation.rotateY(-transform.rotation.y);
    this.translation.rotateX(-transform.rotation.x);
    this.translation.add(transform.translation);
    this.rotation.add(transform.rotation);

}
```

And this part "works" OK. Parent rotated 45 in x,y and z axis with children:

[image: **Parent rotated 45 in x,y and z axis with children**].

"Magic" starts when I try to apply rotation:

```
public void rotateAroundPoint(float dx, float dy, float dz, Transform transform) {
    this.translation.sub(transform.translation);
    this.translation.rotateZ(-(float)Math.toRadians(dz));
    this.translation.rotateY(-(float)Math.toRadians(dy));
    this.translation.rotateX(-(float)Math.toRadians(dx));

    this.translation.add(transform.translation);

    this.rotation.add(dx, dy, dz);
}
```

(Please Note! This is my latest try to implement it and I know it's not working)

When Parent object, and therefore the children, has no rotation applied (at least on different axis than rotation) this rotation works but only on one axis at a time. When ever I try to apply rotation on 2 or 3 axis or on rotated object it fails hard:

[image: **fails hard**]

I've tried implementing Quaternion rotation, changing order of rotation etc. etc. Basically everything I could find here and on uncle Google, yet still couldn't solve this issue. I know it has something with Gimbal Lock, "rotating the rotation" axis and so on.

I was also thinking it might be the problem with `ModelViewMatrix`, but after sitting on this issue with over a week I have no idea what is good and what isn't :P

```
public static Matrix4f getModelViewMatrix(Model model) {
    Quaternion rotation = model.getTransform().rotation;

    MODEL_VIEW_MATRIX.identity()
        .translate(model.getTransform().translation)
        .rotateX(-rotation.x)
        .rotateY(-rotation.y)
        .rotateZ(-rotation.z)
        .scale(model.getTransform().scale);

    viewCurrent.set(VIEW_MATRIX);
    return viewCurrent.mul(MODEL_VIEW_MATRIX);
}
```

What I want to achieve is: When a `GameObject` rotates - each of his child rotates together with him as a one part.

I would appreciate every help you can guys give me :)

Comment: You shouldn't be updating the child objects' transformations if you only move the *parent*. Doing so would lead to lengthy tree traversals and possible float precision problems. Also, a quaternion's XYZ components are *not* the rotation angles in each axis.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog The update logic you see there is only in the init of the game. The update logic will be splited later on. // I know XYZ are not rotation angles but the "result" of rotation around rotation axis. I was thinking about finding the quaternion between 2 vectors  - let's say parent's direction and child's direction to know how to rotate child. Maybe this will work ;)

Comment: The XYZ are not the "result" either (look up how a quaternion is constructed), but let's skip that for now. In the vast majority of 3D engines you *never* rotate a child object; it is always only the "parent" which is updated. The transformation of a child object is with respect to the parent and not the world.

Comment: The problem is that your are splitting your transform into several parts, which makes combining multiple transforms very hard. Just represent the entire transform as a single matrix and you are good. And please don't use Euler angles unless you have a good reason.